# How to determine "event" output to print on the outcome of a random dice roll?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I'm trying to have certain strings print out depending on which dice roll is made.

I have tried making lists for what rolls get which event, but even at that no event prints out only what i have rolled.

```
    import random

    def dice_roll():


      d20_roll = random.randint(1,20)
      print("You rolled " +str(d20_roll))

      def dice_choice():
            event = str(d20_roll)

            bad_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 
            '11', '12']

            good_list = ['13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18']

            gag_list = ['19', '20']

            if event == bad_list:
               print('bad_list stuff')

            elif event == good_list:
                 print('good_list stuff')

            else:
                 if event == print gag_list:
                    print("gag_list stuff")

        dice_choice()
    dice_roll()
```

I expect the output to be any of the three options the random roll will make.
What I receive is just the result of the dice_roll itself, without the choice.

Answer (score 1):

First, check your indentation, your call to `dice_choice()` seems to be inside `dice_choice()` itself, second, there is a syntax error in your test `if event == print gag_list:`, third, you are testing whether a string equals a list, instead you should test whether the string is in the list, your code should be like this:

```
import random

def dice_roll():
    d20_roll = random.randint(1,20)
    print("You rolled " +str(d20_roll))

    def dice_choice():
        event = str(d20_roll)

        bad_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
        good_list = ['13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18']
        gag_list = ['19', '20']

        if event in bad_list:  #  check using `in` not `===`
            print('bad_list stuff')
        elif event in good_list:
            print('good_list stuff')
        elif event == gag_list:
            print("gag_list stuff")

    dice_choice()

dice_roll()
```

Example Output:

```
You rolled 11
bad_list stuff
```